# how to use can-deactivate without routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mean-stack

My problem is I have a parent component and a child component .Parent Component  have  form and child components have forms. All the child component is sharing the same route of parent component and child component don't have any router-link to uniquely identify. So task is to display pop-up when form is dirty and user is navigating away from that page .So I implemented can-deactivate guard. So in "app.module.ts" How can I give can-deactivate to child components(because child components don't have any router-path). How can I achieve this?
any alternative method for detect unsaved changes and display pop-up?plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Noway, it was initially designed to work with routes.

As I understood, Parent and Child forms are completely independent. So, you can define the child component without any URL and put a guard there. See below implementation.

**parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
    <form>
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="text" />
    </form>

    //
    <!-- Here will be your child component -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
class ParentComponent {
  //... your parent form config
  public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  canDiscardChanges() {
    const { valid, pristine } = this.form;

    return valid || pristine;
  }
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
    <form>
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="text" />
    </form>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
class ChildComponentWithForms {
  //... your child form config
  public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  canDiscardChanges() {
    const { valid, pristine } = this.form;

    return valid || pristine;
  }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'parent-route',
        component: ParentComponent,
        canDeactivate: [DiscardChangesGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: ChildComponentWithForms,
            canDeactivate: [DiscardChangesGuard]
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**discard-changes.guard.ts**

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'any' })
export class DiscardChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<IDiscardChanges> {
  canDeactivate(component: IDiscardChanges) {
    if (component.canDiscardChanges instanceof Function) {
      return component.canDiscardChanges();
    }

    return of(true);
  }
}

export interface IDiscardChanges {
  canDiscardChanges(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}
```